# Satisfy numeric solution without analytic one

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I solved an ODE (similar to Blasius equation) $ ~ \phi'''(x) + \phi(x)\phi''(x)=0 ~$ with my 4 stage Runge-Kutta Method and saw that the behaviour of $\phi(x)$ becomes linear, $\phi'(x)$ constant and $\phi(x) \rightarrow 0 $ for $ x \rightarrow  \infty$. 
How can I satisfy that my solution is valid? I cannot compute any points because there is no analytic solution for the equation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try to verify that your solution with stepsize $h=h_0$ satisfies the error order by comparing to the solutions with stepsize $h=2h_0, 4h_0, 8h_0$ and fitting to $ϕ_h(x)\approx ϕ*(x)+C(x)·h^4$ for the last $x$ or a set of sampling points?

Comment: $\phi(x)=a+b\,x$ is a two-parameter family of analytical solutions. They are linear, with constant derivative but do not converge to $0$ as $x\to\infty$ unless $b=0$.

Comment: @LutzL Thank you! I will try this out.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre So a linear behaviour in your eyes is not right? Having a look on http://people.rit.edu/pnveme/ExplictSolutions2/1Dim/NonLinExs/Blassius/Blassius.html you see that it becomes linear for greater values of x...

Comment: A liner behavior seems right. What does not look right is the behavior at $\infty$, but who knows. The particular solutions have initial data $\phi(0)=a$, $\phi'(0)=b$ and $\phi''(0)=0$. May be $\phi''(0)\ne0$ tigers a different behavior.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre I do not agree on that. When I test it, it is $\phi''(0)=\frac{1}{2} a$.

Comment: $(a+b\,x)'=b$, $(a+b\,x)''=(b)'=0$.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I mixed something up. You're right.